# How can I efficiently loop through many prices without repeating myself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having some problems creating a loop that could show the cheapest price.

Here is my controller:

```
   def domain
    country_codes = ['.dk', '.com', '.eu', '.net', '.org', '.biz', '.info', '.nu', '.name', '.se', '.fi', '.net', '.de', '.it'] # etc. could move this to a config if needed
    @domain = params[:domain]
    @results = {}
    country_codes.each do |cc|
    @results[cc] = Whois.whois(@domain + cc)
    end
    @pricedk = Domain.sort("dk ASC").first
    @pricecom = Domain.sort("com ASC").first
    @priceorg = Domain.sort("org ASC").first
    @pricenet = Domain.sort("net ASC").first
    #ETC... 
end
```

My view:

```
<table border="0" bordercolor="#FFCC00" width="700" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="top">
        <td class="checkdomain"></td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Domain</td>
        <td style="font-size:9px;"></td>
    </tr>
     <% @results.each_pair do |country_code, available| %>
    <% klass = available.registered? ? "pinfo" : "info" %>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="<%= klass %>"></span></td>
        <td><%= @domain + country_code %></td>
        <td>PRICE HERE</td>

    </tr>
     <% end %>
</table>
```

I want to DRY the @pricecom, @pricedk, @priceorg up.
How do I include it in the @results loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have repetition like this, with many different instance variables, what you need to do is roll them all up into a single instance variable that's a Hash:

```
def domain
  country_codes = %w[ dk com eu net org biz info nu name se fi net de it ]

  @domain = params[:domain]

  @results = { }
  @prices = { }

  country_codes.each do |cc|
    @results[cc] = Whois.whois("#{@domain}.#{cc}")
    @prices[cc.to_sym] = Domain.sort(cc).first
  end
end
```

You'll see this pattern every so often. `@pricesdk` becomes `@prices[:dk]`

Comment: I have tried @prices[cc.to_sym] = Domain.order(cc) but then I get the hole array. I only want the cc for the array. I have tried @prices[cc.to_sym] = Domain.order(cc).cc but it is not working.

Comment: I just transposed what you had in your original example: `Domain.sort(cc).first` which returns only one record. `Domain.order(cc)` will return all of them sorted. `Domain.order(cc).select(&:cc)` might be what you want.

Comment: Just tried your example get: NoMethodError (undefined method `cc' for #<Domain:0x6f5bb60>):

Comment: You're asking a completely different question now.